# Why didn't Cedric duel with Wormtail?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry and Cedric were transported to the graveyard by the portkey, they saw Wormtail coming to them carrying something. Harry's forehead starting aching wildly so he was unable to duel but Cedric was up and could have fought. But it seems from the passage that it was a complete surrender.

> From far away, above his head, he heard a high, cold voice say, "Kill
>   the spare."
>
> A swishing noise and a second voice, which screeched the words to the
>   night: "Avada Kedavra!"
>
> A blast of green light blazed through Harry's eyelids, and he heard
>   something heavy fall to the ground beside him; the pain in his scar
>   reached such a pitch that he retched, and then it diminished;
>   terrified of what he was about to see, he opened his stinging eyes.
>
> Cedric was lying spread-eagled on the ground beside him. He was dead.

My question is, Cedric didn't know that there was Voldemort in the rags Wormtail was carrying. He was just attacked by a stranger and he should have fought back. But he didn't. I know he was still a student and Wormtail was a fully grown wizard but few minutes later his junior in school was dueling with the most feared dark wizard. Cedric wasn't a coward for sure. So why didn't he duel?

Comment: How do you go about "fighting back" once hit by an unblockable Killing Curse?

Comment: Wormtail didn't start a formal duel. What was Cedric supposed to do? :P Seriously, though - being great at duelling doesn't necessarily translate to being able to defend yourself in a fight. Especially not the first time, after being unexpectedly transported by a port-key into an abandoned graveyard, after an exhausting and potentially deadly competition, with plenty of distractions and an enemy that shoots to kill without provocation. Cedric is not a killer. Wormtail is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It happened too fast for Cedric or Harry to react. They didn't know what they were doing. As your quote suggests, it happens in a blink; they didn't know that something that drastic was going to happen so fast. That said, they were ready, supposedly for a fight.

> "I dunno," said Cedric. He sounded slightly nervous. "Wands out, d'you reckon?"
>
> "Yeah," said Harry, glad that Cedric had made the suggestion rather than him.
>   They pulled out their wands. Harry kept looking around him. He had, yet again, the strange feeling
>   that they were being watched.
>
> "Someone's coming," he said suddenly.

Then they lowered their guard a bit when there wasn't an immediate attack:

> Harry lowered his wand slightly and glanced sideways at Cedric. Cedric shot him a quizzical look.
>   They both turned back to watch the approaching figure.

Furthermore, Harry was rendered helpless, which would've distracted Cedric.

> And then, without warning, Harry's scar exploded with pain. It was agony such as he had never felt in
>   all his life; his wand slipped from his fingers as he put his hands over his face; his knees buckled; he was
>   on the ground and he could see nothing at all; his head was about to split open.

You have to remember there is also nothing that can be done about The Killing Curse. Yes, he should've engaged before then but he's just a seventeen year-old and doesn't know that someone with murderous intent is walking up on them until it is too late.

Comment: you can cast your own curse against the killing curse and both curses collide. that happened a lot between harry and voldemort.

Comment: Only in the movie did  that happen with regularity, and that was more for special effect.

Comment: In the book, only Harry can do this because of the Twin Cores of the two wands they used, as explained in DH

Comment: do you mean that nothing could be done against killing curse. if that was the case killing voldemort would have been so easy, dont you think? anyone just had to throw a killing curse at him. that sounds absurd to me.

Comment: Spoilers DH I think you missed a key part of the books, have you finished the 7th? One of the things that Unforgivable curses require is an urgent desperate psychological WANT of that person dead or tortured. You never see a 'good guy' shoot avada kedavara at people because they simply lack the psychological want to kill. I believe this was explained in another answer I read recently, I'll try to find it. Further, Voldemort couldn't be killed by the Killing Curse because of his Horcruxes, they had to kill all of those first, and then he was killed by a Killing Curse -- his own, rebounding.

Comment: I think there's also something about innocence here. Cedric's death is designed to show "this just got serious kids!" Students like Cedric Diggory are not mentally ready to fight back against evil, murderous and skilled adults. After this moment, Harry takes it upon himself to help them to be ready.

Comment: @DheerajKumar As the Dumbledore-Voldemort duel at the end of OotP (chapter 36) showed, a skilled wizard can block the killing curse with physical objects - or simply avoid it by dodging. *Voldemort raised his wand and another jet of green light streaked at Dumbledore, who turned and was gone in a whirling of his cloak.* ... *Another jet of green light flew from behind the silver shield. This time it was the one-armed centaur, galloping in front of Dumbledore, that took the blast*

Comment: Minor detail : Cedric is not a fourth year. At that point he must be finishing his 6th or 7th year (it's been a while since I read the book, so I don't remember exactly).

Comment: @WraithLeader I find hard to imagine that _nobody_ wanted Voldemort dead enough to be able to pull off an Avada on him. Furthermore, since Avada is distributed like free cookies by the Death Eaters, it doesn't seem it is specially hard to focus the intent needed for the spell to work. Also, Snape used Avada to kill Dumbledore - I don't think he would qualify as having a desperate need to see Dumbledore dead.

Comment: @TheDarkLord goes around fixing my answers :) thanks buddy *backs away slowly*

Comment: @T.Sar I read this thread: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131847/could-draco-kill-dumbledore-with-avada-kedavra
and it influenced my thinking in that respect. It's also supposed to be a good guy vs bad guy thing out of universe, JKR wants to differentiate the people that have a soul, from those that don't. Jury's still out on Mrs. Weasleys' horrific slaughter of Bellatrix Lestrange, an innocent wizard in the wrong place at the wrong time, simply defending herself from one Ginerva Weasley's famed bat-bogey hex.

Comment: Cedric was probably also distracted by Harry collapsing.

Comment: @MissMonicaE that's the third point in my answer, does it need a wording change? :)

Comment: @WraithLeader ah no, I just need to read more carefully. I thought you were just addressing why Harry didn't get into a fight. Sorry!

Comment: @MissMonicaE I figured as much hah I had to go back over it a few times in my head after your comment to make sure I hadn't messed up lol